# How to auto scale Locust in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, locust

I couldn't find any information on autoscaling for Locust worker pods in kubernetes, and I've tried to deploy a horizontal pod autoscaler for the workers but noticed that the newly spun up pods were not assigned any workload.

I've read these on the autoscaling for Locust but failed to find the actual implementation of it:

https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1066

https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1143

https://github.com/locustio/locust/issues/1168

Current the only workaround I found is to scale up the number of pods prior to the loadtest based on GCP's documentation which is not the most ideal solution. (https://cloud.google.com/solutions/distributed-load-testing-using-gke)

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Autoscaling Locust worker nodes is kind of weird since you should know how many you need based on your target RPS, and you don't leave them running after the test since they are single-purpose.

Comment: But what if I want to test different concurrent users at the same time and I want the workers to dynamically scale to the necessary number of pods to create so amount of users? And it should scale down to 0 or 1 when the service is not in use? (I'm referring to the min number of pods setting in hpa)